Compactness of a space of sequences
I consider the set $X=\{ (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} : \forall n\geq 0, x_n\geq 0,\;\sum_{n\geq 0}x_{n}\leq 1 \}$. I would like to show that $(X,d)$ where
$$
d(x,y) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\beta^n\lvert x_n - y_n\rvert,\quad\beta\in (0,1)
$$
is compact.
For this I presume that I need to use the sequentially compactness, so let $(x^m)_{m\geq 0}$ be a sequence in $X$. My first idea was to use a kind of diagonal argument but I cannot see how to articulate this properly, so I wonder if it is the right way to do this.
If you have some hints to provide please (rather than full answer..) it would be helpful.
thank you !

Diagonal argument and Fatou's Lemma should easily finish the proof.

@geetha290krm I will work in this direction, thank you !

Diagonal extraction is indeed a good path: there exists increasing maps $\varphi_n\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that for each $n$, the sequence $\left(x_{n}^{\varphi_1\circ \dots\varphi_n(m)}\right)_{m\geqslant 1}$ converges, say to $y_n$. Then the subsequence $\left(x^{\varphi_1\circ\dots\circ_m(m)}\right)$ is such that for each $n$, $x^{\varphi_1\circ\dots\circ_m(m)}_n\to y_n$.
It remains to check that $y=(y_n)$ belongs to $X$ and that $d\left(x^{\varphi_1\circ\dots\circ_m(m)},y\right)\to 0$. That $y_n\geqslant 0$ is clear. For the condition $\sum_n y_n\leqslant 1$, one has for each $N$ that $\sum_{n=1}^Ny_n=\lim_{m\to\infty}
\sum_{n=1}^Nx^{\varphi_1\circ\dots\circ_m(m)}_n$
and for each $m$, the involved terms are smaller than one hence $\sum_{n=1}^Ny_n\leqslant 1$. Finally, for each $N$,
$$
d\left(x^{\varphi_1\circ\dots\circ_m(m)},y\right)
\leqslant \sum_{n=1}^N\left\lvert x^{\varphi_1\circ\dots\circ_m(m)}_n-y_n\right\rvert+\frac{\beta^N}{1-\beta}.
$$

Thank you for the answer ! It is very clear, however, for the last step, I don't see how you get $\frac{\beta^N}{1-\beta}$ instead of $\frac{c\beta^N}{1-\beta}$  for $c\geq 2$ since we have $\lvert x_{n}^{\varphi_1\circ\cdots\circ\varphi_m(m)}-y_n\rvert\leq 2$ ?

I simply use that if $a,b\in [0,1]$, then $|a-b|\leqslant 1$.

Oh yes the positivity... thank you !
